# Is there a way to calculate up to a certain number?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to find a way to take 20 percent of a number from a cell if it is less than or equal to 3000. And if that number is greater than 3000, let say 7000. I would like to take 20 percent of 3000 from that 7000 and just add the remaining 4000. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Slight correction to the second part of JvdV's answer:
`=IF(A1<=3000,0.2*A1,3000*0.2+A1-3000)`

Comment: That's not a correction. I just simplified `3000*0.2+A1-3000` @Learning Ahh.

Comment: Learning Ahh mentioned the 7000 as an example (for instance), so the formula needed to work for possible other values as well.

Comment: Have you actually checked what the outcome would be with other values. The simplicication would work on any value you throw at the formula.

Comment: You're correct. But with the clarification now added one can reproduce the thoughts. It eventually is the better version indeed.